# Synchronously load "bunch of different resources" in browser

Tags: javascript, multithreading, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have scenario like following:

'on button click' I need to update part of the page using dynamically selected JavaScript routine. It, in turn, internally, my call other dynamically selected JavaScript routines. Some routines know beforehand that they will further call N other routines. All of them update DOM and add some CSS (loaded from separate files too).

Currently this staff is working synchronously - resources are loaded one by one (synchronous XHR) and executed (JS eval). The problem is that, of course, page becomes unresponsive. 'unresponsives' is OK, but for a short period and I'm looking for the way to reduce the not-responsive time by parallel loading of the known resources - i would like to get functionality like following: "start 5 async XHR's" and "synchronously wait for all of them to complete". Unfortunately XHR does not provide such API - only callbacks are possible, but this not appropriate because ...

- keeping actual rendering context via callbacks would be extremly difficult
- rendering with callbacks will cause constant repaint with noticeable flicker, fixing that by 'off DOM' rendering will also require significant effort
- another deal will be 'state control' - ensure if user actions do not brake the state of the rendring process (i'm aware about 'block UI', but thins may not be such easy)

So ... is there way to "wait synchronously" for completion of multiple "async XHRs"? BTW, i'm not looking specifically onto XHRs - any applicable API available in IE10+ is OK.

BTW: Web Workers do not fit because of the same reason - not possible to synchronously check their status, only via async 'onmessage' event.

Comment: Well you need to code your page to be able to work in an asynchronous manner. Plenty of libraries that load resources like require.js are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Probably you are looking for sort of `Deferred` functionality, which jQuery provides with [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object?

Comment: "Asynchronous manner" in my case will be "spaghetti code" everyone complains about in node.js. Therefore I'm still trying to find "good" synchronous solution.